# How do I return the SQL data types from my query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I've a SQL query that queries an enormous (as in, hundreds of views/tables with hard-to-read names like CMM-CPP-FAP-ADD) database that I don't need nor want to understand.  The result of this query needs to be stored in a staging table to feed a report.

I need to create the staging table, but with hundreds of views/tables to dig through to find the data types that are being represented here, I have to wonder if there's a better way to construct this table.

Can anyone advise how I would use any of the SQL Server 2008 tools to divine the source data types in my SQL 2000 database?

As a general example, I want to know from a query like:

```
SELECT Auth_First_Name, Auth_Last_Name, Auth_Favorite_Number 
FROM Authors
```

Instead of the actual results, I want to know that:

```
Auth_First_Name is char(25)
Auth_Last_Name is char(50)
Auth_Favorite_Number is int
```

I'm not interested in constraints, I really just want to know the data types.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
select * from information_schema.columns
```

could get you started.

Comment: Do you have a CASE SENSITIVE database? If so, you must use `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns`

Comment: Yes, it is case sensitive.  I tried SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns and get the same invalid object error.  This is SQL Server 2000 (8.0.2055), does INFORMATION_SCHEMA exist in this version?

Comment: ok nvm, I tried SELECT * FROM [databasename].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUNMS and I'm getting somewhere.  Thanks for being patient with me on this!

Comment: This doesn't help if you're actually trying to select the data types returned in a query - this only evaluates the static table definition.  [See @redcalx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46362346/2738164) below for an actual solution when fed an arbitrary query.

Answer (score 85):

For SQL Server 2012 and above: If you place the query into a string then you can get the result set data types like so:

```
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = 'select 12.1 / 10.1 AS [Column1]';
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set @query, null, 0;
```

Comment: Great answer! Where can I learn another useful sp_ procedures like this?

Comment: This is GOLD for Determining the Datatype of AdHoc Scripted Columns!  Before, I was using Select-Into and then studying the new Table Schema that was created.  This is much faster!

Answer (score 38):

You could also insert the results (or top 10 results) into a temp table and get the columns from the temp table (as long as the column names are all different).

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
INTO #TempTable
FROM <DataSource>
```

Then use:

```
EXEC tempdb.dbo.sp_help N'#TempTable';
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM tempdb.sys.columns 
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TempTable');
```

Extrapolated from [Aaron's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7486974/641833).

Answer (score 33):

You can also use...

```
SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY()
```

...in cases where you don't have direct access to the metadata (e.g. a linked server query perhaps?).

- [SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sql-variant-property-transact-sql)

In SQL Server 2005 and beyond you are better off using the catalog views (sys.columns) as opposed to INFORMATION_SCHEMA.  Unless portability to other platforms is important.  Just keep in mind that the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views won't change and so they will progressively be lacking information on new features etc. in successive versions of SQL Server.

Comment: This will not work for text fields. Will throw this exception: "Operand type clash: text is incompatible with sql_variant"

Comment: @eflles Thanks, remember this is an exceptional case (when you don't have access to the metadata) and, even in 2009 when this question came up, you should have abandoned `text`, `ntext`, and `image`. If people are still using those today, this is but a small part of their problems...

Answer (score 26):

There **MUST** be en easier way to do this... Low and behold, there is...!

"**sp_describe_first_result_set**" is your friend!

Now I do realise the question was asked specifically for SQL Server 2000, but I was looking for a similar solution for later versions and discovered some native support in SQL to achieve this.

In SQL Server 2012 onwards cf. "sp_describe_first_result_set" - [Link to BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx)

I had already implemented a solution using a technique similar to [@Trisped's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26067533/641833) above and ripped it out to implement the native SQL Server implementation.

In case you're not on SQL Server 2012 or Azure SQL Database yet, here's the stored proc I created for pre-2012 era databases:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [fn].[GetQueryResultMetadata] 
    @queryText VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    --SET NOCOUNT ON;

    PRINT @queryText;

    DECLARE
                @sqlToExec NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
                    'SELECT TOP 1 * INTO #QueryMetadata FROM ('
                    +
                    @queryText
                    +
                    ') T;'
                    + '
                        SELECT
                                    C.Name                          [ColumnName],
                                    TP.Name                         [ColumnType],
                                    C.max_length                    [MaxLength],
                                    C.[precision]                   [Precision],
                                    C.[scale]                       [Scale],
                                    C.[is_nullable]                 IsNullable
                        FROM
                                    tempdb.sys.columns              C
                                        INNER JOIN
                                    tempdb.sys.types                TP
                                                                                ON
                                                                                        TP.system_type_id = C.system_type_id
                                                                                            AND
                                                                                        -- exclude custom types
                                                                                        TP.system_type_id = TP.user_type_id
                        WHERE
                                    [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N''tempdb..#QueryMetadata'');
            '

    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlToExec

END
```

Answer (score 15):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,
       DATA_TYPE,
       CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
```

You can use columns aliases for better looking output.

Answer (score 6):

Can you get away with recreating the staging table from scratch every time the query is executed? If so you could use [`SELECT ... INTO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx) syntax and let SQL Server worry about creating the table using the correct column types etc.

```
SELECT *
INTO your_staging_table
FROM enormous_collection_of_views_tables_etc
```

Comment: He could also create that staging table just to get the columns data types, using the information_schema table pointed by erikkallen.

Comment: @JM: How about running the `SELECT ... INTO ... FROM ... WHERE 1=0` syntax as a one-off to create a dummy table, and then use Management Studio to script the table creation SQL for the dummy table?

Comment: This is very helpful when the data source is a table value function, in which case you can not use `information_schema.columns`. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This will give you everything column property related.

```
SELECT * INTO TMP1
FROM ( SELECT TOP 1 /* rest of your query expression here */ );

SELECT o.name AS obj_name, TYPE_NAME(c.user_type_id) AS type_name, c.*  
FROM sys.objects AS o   
JOIN sys.columns AS c  ON o.object_id = c.object_id  
WHERE o.name = 'TMP1';

DROP TABLE TMP1;
```

Comment: This is by far the most concise answer to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

```
select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME='yourTable';
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution to visualize the max len too (e.g. VarChar len)

Answer (score 2):

> sp_describe_first_result_set

will help to identify the datatypes of query by analyzing datatypes of first resultset of query

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: This isn't a valid answer because OP specifically stated that they have a SQL 2000 database. This procedure wasn't introduced until 2012.

Answer (score 2):

I use a simple case statement to render results I can use in technical specification documents.  This example does not contain every condition you will run into with a database, but it gives you a good template to work with.

```
SELECT
     TABLE_NAME          AS 'Table Name',
     COLUMN_NAME         AS 'Column Name',
     CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE LIKE '%char'
          THEN DATA_TYPE + '(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH) + ')'
          WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('bit', 'int', 'smallint', 'date')
          THEN DATA_TYPE
          WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'datetime'
          THEN DATA_TYPE + '(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATETIME_PRECISION) + ')'
          WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'float'
          THEN DATA_TYPE
          WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('numeric', 'money')
          THEN DATA_TYPE + '(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, NUMERIC_PRECISION) + ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX) + ')'
     END                 AS 'Data Type',
     CASE WHEN IS_NULLABLE = 'NO'
          THEN 'NOT NULL'
          ELSE 'NULL'
     END                 AS 'PK/LK/NOT NULL'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
ORDER BY 
     TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Answer (score 2):

Checking data types.
The first way to check data types for SQL Server database is a query with the SYS schema table. The below query uses COLUMNS and TYPES tables:

```
    SELECT C.NAME AS COLUMN_NAME,
       TYPE_NAME(C.USER_TYPE_ID) AS DATA_TYPE,
       C.IS_NULLABLE,
       C.MAX_LENGTH,
       C.PRECISION,
       C.SCALE
FROM SYS.COLUMNS C
JOIN SYS.TYPES T
     ON C.USER_TYPE_ID=T.USER_TYPE_ID
WHERE C.OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('your_table_name');
```

In this way, you can find data types of columns.

Answer (score 0):

This easy query return a data type bit. You can use this thecnic for other data types:

select CAST(0 AS BIT) AS OK