# Finding the data types of a SQL temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to switch from using a #temp table to a @table variable so that I can use it in a function.

My query uses insert into #temp (from multiple tables) like so:

```
SELECT 
  a.col1, 
  a.col2, 
  b.col1... 
INTO #temp
FROM ...
```

Is there an easy way to find out the data types of the columns in the #temp table so that I can create the @table variable with the same columns and data types as #temp?

Comment: @AaronBertrand is right but the answer from @gotqn is excellent for none `temp` tables.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

You need to make sure `sp_help` runs in the same database where the table is located (tempdb). You can do this by prefixing the call directly:

```
EXEC tempdb.dbo.sp_help @objname = N'#temp';
```

Or by prefixing a join against `tempdb.sys.columns`:

```
SELECT [column] = c.name, 
       [type] = t.name, c.max_length, c.precision, c.scale, c.is_nullable 
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns AS c
    INNER JOIN tempdb.sys.types AS t
    ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
    AND t.system_type_id = t.user_type_id
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#temp');
```

This doesn't handle nice things for you, like adjusting max_length for varchar differently from nvarchar, but it's a good start.

In SQL Server 2012 or better, you can use a new DMF to describe a resultset, which takes that issue away (and also assembles max_length/precision/scale for you). But it doesn't support #temp tables, so just inject the query *without the INTO*:

```
SELECT name, system_type_name, is_nullable
  FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'SELECT 
        a.col1, 
        a.col2, 
        b.col1... 
      --INTO #temp
      FROM ...;',NULL,1);
```

Comment: I liked the second suggestion but it didn't provide types in text so here it is joined up with data types.

´SELECT cols.column_id,cols.name,ty.name,cols.max_length,cols.precision,cols.scale
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns cols
 join sys.types ty on cols.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#myTable');´

Comment: I want to do this in redshift, is it possible?

Comment: I know this answer is over 10 years old but wanted to add that `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set`  on Azure SQL database supports temp tables

`SELECT name, system_type_name, is_nullable
  FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set
 (N'SELECT 
        *
      FROM #temptable;',NULL,1); `

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer does not give the data type.Joining tempdb.sys.columns with sys.types gives the data type as mentioned in the comment of the answer.But joining on  system_type_id yields one extra row with datatype "sysname". Instead "user_type_id"  gives the exact solution as given below.

```
SELECT cols.NAME
 ,ty.NAME
FROM tempdb.sys.columns cols
JOIN sys.types ty ON cols.user_type_id = ty.user_type_id
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp')
```

Comment: To extend this answer further, you could also select max_length, precision, scale and is_nullable from tempdb.sys.columns to get the maximum length, precision, scale and whether or not the column can be null or not.

Answer (score 10):

you need to qualify the sp_help process to run from the tempdb database to get details about a hash table, because that's where the hash table is actually stored.  If you attempt to run sp_help from a different database you'll get an error that the table doesn't exist in that database.

If your query is executing outside of tempdb, as I assume it is, you can run the following:

```
exec tempdb..sp_help #temp
```

One benefit of this procedure is it includes a text description of the column datatypes for you.  This makes it very easy to copy and paste into another query, e.g. if you're trying use the definition of a temp table to create a table variable.

You could find the same information in the Syscolumns table, but it will give you numeric indentifiers for the types which you'll have to map yourself.  Using sp_help will save you a step.

Comment: Thanks for this, way better than the accepted answer because it actually explains what's being done and why.

Answer (score 7):

**Finding the data types of a SQL temporary table**

***METHOD 1 – Using SP_HELP***

```
EXEC TempDB..SP_HELP #TempTable;
```

[image]

*Note-*

In the Table Structure, the Table Name shows something like ‘#TempTable__________________________________________________________________________________________________________0000000004CB’. Actually, the total length of each and every Temp Table name will be 128 . To handle the Same Temp Table name in Multiple Sessions differently, SQL Server will automatically add some underscores in between and alphanumeric’s at end.

***METHOD 2 – Using SP_COLUMNS***

```
EXEC TempDB..SP_COLUMNS '#TempTable';
```

[image]

***METHOD 3 – Using System Tables like INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, SYS.COLUMNS, SYS.TABLES***

```
SELECT * FROM TempDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME IN (
SELECT NAME FROM TempDB.SYS.TABLES WHERE OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('TempDB.dbo.#TempTable')
);
GO

SELECT * FROM TempDB.SYS.COLUMNS WHERE OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('TempDB.dbo.#TempTable');
GO

SELECT * FROM TempDB.SYS.TABLES WHERE OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('TempDB.dbo.#TempTable');
GO
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The other answers will give you the information that you need, but still require you to type it all out when you define the table variable.

The following TSQL will allow you to quickly generate the table variable's definition for any given table.

This can save you a lot of time instead of manually typing table definitions like:

```
table(Field1Name nvarchar(4), Field2Name nvarchar(20), Field3Name int
, Field4Name numeric(28,12))
```

TSQL:

```
select top 10 * 
into #temp
from db.dbo.myTable



declare @tableName nvarchar(max)
set @tableName = '#temp'

use tempdb
declare @tmp table(val nvarchar(max))
insert into @tmp 
select case data_type   
    when 'binary' then COLUMN_NAME + ' ' + DATA_TYPE + '(' + cast(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS nvarchar(max)) + ')'
    when 'char' then COLUMN_NAME + ' ' + DATA_TYPE + '(' + cast(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS nvarchar(max)) + ')'
    when 'datetime2' then COLUMN_NAME + ' ' + DATA_TYPE + '(' + CAST(DATETIME_PRECISION as nvarchar(max)) + ')'
    when 'datetimeoffset' then COLUMN_NAME + ' ' + DATA_TYPE + '(' + CAST(DATETIME_PRECISION as nvarchar(max)) + ')'
    when 'decimal' then COLUMN_NAME + ' ' + DATA_TYPE + '(' + cast(NUMERIC_PRECISION as nvarchar(max)) + ',' + cast(NUMERIC_SCALE as nvarchar(max)) + ')'
    when 'nchar' then COLUMN_NAME + ' ' + DATA_TYPE + '(' + cast(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS nvarchar(max)) + ')'
    when 'numeric' then COLUMN_NAME + ' ' + DATA_TYPE + '(' + cast(NUMERIC_PRECISION as nvarchar(max)) + ',' + cast(NUMERIC_SCALE as nvarchar(max)) + ')'
    when 'nvarchar' then COLUMN_NAME + ' ' + DATA_TYPE + '(' + cast(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS nvarchar(max)) + ')'
    when 'time' then COLUMN_NAME + ' ' + DATA_TYPE + '(' + CAST(DATETIME_PRECISION as nvarchar(max)) + ')'
    when 'varbinary' then COLUMN_NAME + ' ' + DATA_TYPE + '(' + cast(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS nvarchar(max)) + ')'
    when 'varchar' then COLUMN_NAME + ' ' + DATA_TYPE + '(' + cast(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS nvarchar(max)) + ')'
    -- Most standard data types follow the pattern in the other section.  
    -- Non-standard datatypes include: binary, char, datetime2, datetimeoffset, decimal, nvchar, numeric, nvarchar, time, varbinary, and varchar
    else COLUMN_NAME + ' ' + DATA_TYPE

    end +  case when IS_NULLABLE <> 'YES' then ' NOT NULL' else '' end 'dataType'
     from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME like @tableName + '%'

declare @result nvarchar(max)
set @result = ''
select @result = @result + [val] + N','
from @tmp
where val is not null

set @result = substring(@result, 1, (LEN(@result)-1))

-- The following will replce '-1' with 'max' in order to properly handle nvarchar(max) columns
set @result = REPLACE(@result, '-1', 'max')
select @result
```

Output:

```
Field1Name nvarchar(4), Field2Name nvarchar(20), Field3Name int
, Field4Name numeric(28,12)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for today

Answer (score 4):

to get columns name with data type use this

```
EXEC tempdb.dbo.sp_help N'#temp';
```

or
To get only columns name to use this

```
SELECT * 
FROM tempdb.sys.columns 
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#temp');
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd go the lazy route and use

```
use tempdb
GO
EXECUTE sp_help #temp
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is to get information about the system types of the columns you are querying.

For `SQL Server 2012 and later` you can use [sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878258.aspx) function. It returns very detailed information about the columns and the `system_type_column` holds the complete  system type definition (ready to use in your table definition):

For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [sys].[dm_exec_describe_first_result_set] (N'SELECT object_id, name, type_desc FROM sys.indexes', null, 0);
```

[image]

Comment: I get the error "The metadata could not be determined because statement 'SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.#T' uses a temp table." for temp tables...

Comment: Check the following article about the limitations - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878258.aspx - see the `Remarks` section.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the data types of the temp table will be the data types of the columns you are selecting and inserting into it. So just look at the select statement and determine each data type based on the column you select.

Comment: Thanks - I realise that you can do it this way but it becomes a pain having to check through multiple columns and tables, especially if its a huge temp table.

Comment: @woggles I see. billinkc's `lazy` approach suits you better in that case.

Comment: now I need just need to find nice lazy way to script out the declare @ table statement :)

Comment: @woggles I don't know if there's a lazy approach for that but this will tell you column names, data types and length of each, in a result set that you can iterate over and create the script yourself building the SQL statement dynamically. `SELECT sc.name,st.name as type_name ,sc.max_length
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns sc
    
    inner join sys.types st on st.system_type_id=sc.system_type_id
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp');`

Comment: @woggles it's a pain in current versions of SQL Server (don't forget about precision and scale, conditionals for halving max_length for nvarchar, changing max_length to `MAX` if it is -1, dealing with alias types, table types, CLR types)... in Denali there will be a much better way using metadata discovery features: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/12/20/sql-server-v-next-denali-metadata-discovery.aspx