# INSERT INTO temp table fails in SQL Server, but same statement runs perfectly in PostgreSQL, MySQL, & SQLite

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

We are writing an in-house 'speed test' program, for learning / training purposes (and curiosity), that works with several back-ends - PostgreSQL, SQL Server, MySQL, & SQLite.

The program creates a temp table in the respective back-end (which is a simple copy of the main source table), so we can test UPDATE and INSERT commands on this (without trashing the main source data).  It also creates a temp subset table of 1000 records.  Then it runs several timing tests that iterate through the 1000 subset records for a particular SQL operation:  SELECT, UPDATE, and INSERT.

All tests run perfectly in PostgreSQL, MySQL, & SQLite. SQL Server runs the SELECT & UPDATE tests fine, but errors out on all 1000 INSERT commands - which only specify a few columns / values.

(PostgreSQL & SQLite assigned NULL values to all columns not specified in the INSERT command. MySQL assigned NULL values only to unspecified columns with a DATE or TEXT data type. MySQL assigned empty values of 0 to unspecified numeric columns, and a string of spaces (of correct length) to 'VarChar' columns.)

SQL Server INSERT INTO worked perfectly for populating its main source tables (we repeat the tests over several different ones).  But this process specified a value for every column in the table (except the primary key).

So we suspect that the failures of the INSERT operations, in the test itself (which only specifies a few columns), might be due to SQL Server having brought the "not null" constraints from the main source table over into the temp table, but not the default values.  Of course, it may be due to something else completely.  But either way, we are stumped.

The SQL command we use for creating (successfully) the large temp table in SQL Server is:

`select * into #TmpJobs from Jobs`

All the other back-ends are ANSI compliant. So for these, we use the command:

`create temporary table TmpJobs as select * from Jobs`

SQL Server even rejects the following very simple insert command (it makes no difference if the field name is all upper or lower case):

`insert into #TmpJobs (JobCode) values ('J1')`

We are using SQLExpress 2019. When viewed through SSMS, there are no entries in the Management > SQL Server Logs > Current file, that give diagnostic info on the failed INSERT commands.

Can anyone see what we are missing, and suggest how we can get it to work for simple INSERT operations (that don't specify values for all fields)?

**Added on Nov 5:**
Thanks for your replies "Dale K".
I have run the following in SSMS, as you suggested, and this gave much more useful diagnostic info:

```
Use AdminsoftTest
select * into #TmpJobs from AdminsoftApps.Jobs
insert into #TmpJobs (JobCode) values ('J1')
```

This gave the error message for line 3:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ClientCode', table 'tempdb.dbo.#TmpJobs___...
; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

So it seems that the "NOT NULL" column criteria have indeed been carried over to the temp table, but not the DEFAULT values.

Does anyone know an easy way to set all columns of a temp table to "Nullable"?

(Alternatively, does anyone know of a good template stored procedure that would set sensible empty default values (0 for numeric, etc.) to all columns of a temp table?)

Comment: What error are you getting on MS-SQL?

Comment: Its not clear to me what is actually not working here. For a start, ignore what is happening with other database engines, they are all different. Please provide the exact set of statements (all of them) for SQL Server and then explain exactly at what point they fail, and how.

Comment: We are using an ODBC agent for the interface to SQL Server.  It is a bit limited, in that it only returns an error flag as a numeric value of -1.

Comment: Those commands are all that is involved - the tests are very simple. The rest of the program logic is just setting a timing variable, and a loop through all records of the subset - i.e. would just be extra clutter.

Comment: We are currently working up the same test program in Python, which hopefully will give much better diagnostic info.

Comment: I believe in SQL Server, if you create a temp table via SELECT ... INTO, and a column is determined to be not NULLABLE, then it gets flagged as NOT NULL. but On the other hand it may not inherit (say) IDENTITY settings. If you wish to do additional data inserts/updates on the temp table, it is often better to explicitly create it rather than selecting into it - or you can use some tricks e.g., https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/04/select-into-and-non-nullable-columns/ -

Comment: So are you saying that you are running the following 2 simple statements and getting a -1 back `select * into #TmpJobs from Jobs; insert into #TmpJobs (JobCode) values ('J1')`? Try running the actual commands within SSMS first - then you will get better error handling. You can [test the definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486941/finding-the-data-types-of-a-sql-temporary-table) of your temp table. Having just tried it in SSMS at least one issue will be columns which don't allow nulls.

Comment: You can alter the definition of columns in the temp table once created to allow nulls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:  Add a "default" table constraint for each column**

In the application, we added a loop through all field names in the temp table, which ran SQL Server commands to add a "default" table constraint for each column, except for the primary key column (RowID).  The INSERT commands, that specified only some columns, then worked perfectly.

Note: SQL Server returned an error when we attempted to set a default value of 0 to RowID.  So, it seems this 'RowID' table constraint (of primary key) was copied over from the source table, (unless SQL Server always treats a column named "RowID" as being a primary key).

Here is a summary of the successful SQL command sequence from our application:

```
select * into AdminsoftApps.#TmpJobs from AdminsoftApps.Jobs
alter table #TmpJobs add constraint DefaultJobCode default ' ' for JobCode
alter table #TmpJobs add constraint DefaultClientCode default ' ' for ClientCode
...  etc. (There are 45 fields in the Jobs table)
```

Our application's program line (within a loop through 1,000 records) then worked:

```
insert into AdminsoftApps.TmpJobs (JobCode, ClientCode, ...) values ( ... )
```

In our application's INSERT test, we specified only 10 columns and values for each inserted record. After adding the new default table constraints, SQL Server accepted all 1,000 INSERT commands, and nicely populated all other fields with their default empty values in each new record.

The following (specifying just a few columns in the SELECT) worked in SSMS:

```
Use AdminsoftTest
drop table #TmpJobs
select JobCode, JobName, ClientCode, AddrRecID into AdminsoftApps.#TmpJobs from AdminsoftApps.Jobs
alter table #TmpJobs add constraint DefaultJobCode default ' ' for JobCode
alter table #TmpJobs add constraint DefaultJobName default ' ' for JobName
alter table #TmpJobs add constraint DefaultClientCode default ' ' for ClientCode
alter table #TmpJobs add constraint DefaultAddrRecID default ' ' for AddrRecID
insert into AdminsoftApps.#TmpJobs (JobCode) values ('J1')
```

**Wider Understanding about NOT NULL Column Constraints**

It seems that SQL Server automatically applies NOT NULL constraints to every column of a temporary table created by a SELECT ...INTO...

In our tests it rejected "ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN *FieldName* NULL" statements that attempted to change these to NULL instead. (There were no NULL values in the existing data in those columns at the time.)

---

**Unsuccessful Attempts to Clear NOT NULL Column Constraints:**

The rest of this 'answer' below, is provided only for those who are interested in reading further about our attempts to clear the IS NULL constraints:

We first ran the following simple test in SSMS to verify that SQL Server automatically applies a NOT NULL constraint to all columns of a temp table created by a SELECT ...INTO...:

```
Use AdminsoftTest
select '   ' as CharField1,  '   ' as CharField2, 100 as NumericField1
       into #TmpTest from AdminsoftApps.Jobs where RowID <= 3
insert into #TmpTest (CharField1) values ('J1')
```

Note:  All columns in the SELECT are created from literal values - none are brought through from the source Jobs table, which is merely used to initialize #TmpTest with 3 empty records.

This produced the following error message:

```
(3 rows affected)
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CharField2', table 'AdminsoftTest.dbo.#TmpTest';
 column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

So it seems that SQL Server does automatically apply IS NULL constraints to all columns - even new ones created from literal values (that are not in the source table specified in the SELECT).

It also seems that SQL Server rejects any attempt to change these IS NULL column constraints of a temp table created by a SELECT ...INTO..., because the following also failed:

```
Use AdminsoftTest
drop table #TmpTest
select '   ' as CharField1,  '   ' as CharField2, 100 as NumericField1
       into #TmpTest from AdminsoftApps.Jobs where RowID <= 3
alter table #TmpTest alter column CharField2 NULL
```

The error message for this was:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NULL'.
```

However the syntax for line 5 above seems to conform to the specification in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15   (It could be that we have messed up on this, and I would appreciate feedback if anyone can give me a corrected syntax for this command - that SQL Server accepts and applies correctly.)

**Quirks with tests using SSMS** (For interest only)

We were pleasantly surprised that we could get it to work in the application, because the (much simpler) tests we did using SSMS were pretty inconsistent and unsuccessful - and confusing.

The SSMS tests that used literal values to create several new columns (and no fields from the source table) worked.  However, those that had a mixture of one live field and columns created from literals, did not work.

Here is sample test code that adds table constraints - and provides an INSERT example that did work in SSMS:

```
Use AdminsoftTest
select '   ' as CharField1,  '   ' as CharField2, 100 as NumericField1
       into #TmpTest from AdminsoftApps.Jobs where RowID <= 3
alter table #TmpTest add constraint CharField2Default default ' ' for CharField2
alter table #TmpTest add constraint NumericField1Default default 0 for NumericField1
insert into #TmpTest (CharField1) values ('J1')
```

However, for some reason, SQL Server spits the dummy with commands that attempt to insert values into fields that came from the original source table:

```
Use AdminsoftTest
drop table #TmpTest
select JobCode, '   ' as CharField1,  '   ' as CharField2, 100 as NumericField1
       into #TmpTest from AdminsoftApps.Jobs where RowID <= 3
alter table #TmpTest add constraint JobCodeDefault default ' ' for JobCode
alter table #TmpTest add constraint CharField1Default default ' ' for CharField1
alter table #TmpTest add constraint CharField2Default default ' ' for CharField2
alter table #TmpTest add constraint NumericField1Default default 0 for NumericField1
insert into #TmpTest (JobCode) values ('J1')
```

This produced an error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Invalid column name 'JobCode'.
```

However, the following works:

```
Use AdminsoftTest
drop table #TmpTest
select JobCode, '   ' as CharField1,  '   ' as CharField2, 100 as NumericField1
       into #TmpTest from AdminsoftApps.Jobs where RowID <= 3
alter table #TmpTest add constraint JobCodeDefault default ' ' for JobCode
alter table #TmpTest add constraint CharField1Default default ' ' for CharField1
alter table #TmpTest add constraint CharField2Default default ' ' for CharField2
alter table #TmpTest add constraint NumericField1Default default 0 for NumericField1
insert into #TmpTest (CharField1) values ('J1')
```

This is pretty inconsistent. It accepts the 'JobCode' column in Line 5, but rejects it in Line 9. It accepts a value for a new column that was created from a string literal, but not for a column that came from the original source table.  I would appreciate any feedback that explains why SSMS could not insert a value  into the 'JobCode' column (and presumably, any other columns in the temp table that come from the original source table).

I hope this extra info is helpful to someone...

Regards
Graeme Evans